# How to make one animation bone control many other bones?

Tags: animation

How do I make so that I have a controler bone that moves the other bones?
If I move the top bone of the controler the other bones should do the same.

I have heard about constrains but I dont really now how they work.

[image]

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  You can parent the other bones to the control bone; use copy constraints; or a driver.  The best one would depend on how the animator would use the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pose mode, give a *Copy Rotation* constraint to the bone that is supposed to copy the rotation of another bone, and choose this other bone as *Target*. As your other bone chains are similar, you can simply duplicate in *Edit* mode, it will duplicate the constraint as well:

[image]

Comment: You are my new spiritual animal :) thank you man